# Donut chart d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I try to modify [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) example. I would like to create two data arrays and merge them using special `mergingAr()` function instead of `data.csv`. But it does not work. There is one-colour chart without any data. I can`t find the problem place in the code. So, here it is:

```
var width = 250,
    height = 250,
    radius = 230;

var arr1 = [44, 64]; //age
var arr2 = [14106543, 8819342]; //population

function type(d) {
  d[1] = +d[1];
  return d;
}

function mergingAr(array1, array2)
{

    var i, out = [];
    for(i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
    {
        out.push([array1[i],array2[i]]);
    }
        return out;
   }

var data = mergingAr(arr1, arr2);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#EB7221", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 100)
    .innerRadius(radius - 180);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d[1]; }); 

var svg = d3.select("#pie").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d[0]); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d[0]; }); 


      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is there, but your color is wrong. Right now, you have this line setting path color:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d[0]); });
```

The problem is that your data is an object, not an array. (It's transformed by the `pie` function), so you need to reference the `data` attribute on the object, and then get the zero index of that array, like so:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data[0]); });
```